# Where store downloaded images in app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have app in which I'm downloading image from web to iphone app. This part is working.

Part which is problem is where to store it?

For store location I'm using this code:

```
...
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", docDir, imageName];
...
```

But I when I start app in iPhone simulator, images are not loaded.

When I store images to desktop I see images but still are not loaded.

```
NSString *docDir = @"/Users/username/Desktop/MyProject/";
```

Where and how store images and then load them?

Comment: Do you need a slash in `@"%@%@"`, i.e. shouldn't it be `@"%@/%@"`?

Comment: noap. When I print this docDir in NSLOG it's ends with slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this website will help you :

http://guerratopia.com/en/how-to-saveload-or-remove-images-in-iphoneipad-documents-directory

If you follow his instructions it will work.

Cheers Max

EDIT: And I think dasblinkenlight is right.

Comment: Thank you for this link. I implemented this into my app and it work's great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *pngFilePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
```